# How can an intelligent, STL interstellar civilisation emerge on a planet with an ammonia-based biochemistry?

Tags: xenobiology, hard-science

So, while thinking over the Visitor series, I kind of had this idea that beyond the events of the Sol System, there were four other interstellar civilisations besides the Xwlnnr (also known as the aforementioned Visitors to the humans), and one of them involved an interstellar species with an ammonia-based biochemistry whose home system is located 17,000 light years away from Earth in the Carina-Sagittarius Arm of the Milky Way Galaxy, likely located in the Carina constellation. The issue is...what kind of conditions would be a requisite to develop an ammonia-based biosphere for complex life, assuming that is even possible, especially one capable of hosting the home planet of an interstellar civilisation?

Comment: [Hypothetical types of biochemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry), especially the section [Ammonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry#Ammonia). As for the rest, as far as we know the human kind of intelligence, curiosity and drive to explore were pure accidents. Our close cousins the chimpanzees seem to live perfectly happy lives without feeling a need to develop calculus.

Comment: @AlexP. I read that, but...does that apply to complex life on the planet as well (especially one that could develop intelligence and even an STL interstellar civilisation)?

Comment: Are you sure you want hard-science on this?

Comment: @Mołot. Yes. I do...

Answer (score 3):

We have strong reasons to think life can arise in a reducing atmosphere.  (It almost certainly did on Earth.)  Life has shown an amazing ability to evolve to use whatever energy sources are available.  (E.g., life at undersea vents and in solid rock miles down.)

So life evolving in your NH<sub>3</sub>-dominated atmosphere seems like a safe event.

On Earth, prokaryotic (basically bacterial) life evolved quickly (~ half billion years). Once that happened, it seems to have taken ~two billion years to evolve eukaryotic life (still single celled, but *much* larger and more complicated.)

Once the Eukaryotes evolved it was a fairly short ~half billion year jump to multicellular life.  ~billion years later the Cambrian Explosion swept the world with complex lifeforms. Intelligence appeared ~half billion years after that.

There's no reason to think that once an ammonia-based biochemistry evolved, subsequent evolution would be markedly different than on Earth. (It might be slower, it might be faster; we just don't know.)  Likewise, insofar as we know, multi-celluarism and intelligence are basically independent of the underlying biochemistry.

The bottom line is that from the evidence to date (one planet!) intelligence is easier to evolve than eukaryotes or big animals.

So if the planet is old enough, intelligent life is a pretty good bet.

Comment: The question is less about the possibility of complex, ammonia-based life and more about the requirements. So, how do you make the ammonia-based life evolve beyond simple bacteria in the first place to develop life complex enough to develop an interstellar civilisation?

Comment: You can't *stop* life from evolving. We know of nothing at all which would prevent ammonia-based life from following the same pattern as Earthly life did once the basic biochemistry was established.  Thus the history of life on Earth is the only actual evidence we have and is directly relevant. And it says that the jump from prokaryotes to animals takes billions of years, but does happen.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense.